# can anyone explain to me why when i set the body's background color his causes my other css styles to be ignored

Tags: css

Whenever I set the background color for my body it ignores the CSS styles that come after it. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```css
 body{
  background-color:gray;
 };
 
 h1 {
   text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run your CSS through a CSS validator.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon after the first set of braces is causing the CSS parsing to fail.

Remove it and it will work as expected :

```css
 body{
  background-color:gray;
 }
 
 h1 {
   text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why this answer is negative mark..?

Comment: @chandershekhar They live among us. This answer is correct.

Comment: It's a "typo". Typos should be closed with the "typo" close reason (under "off-topic"); that's why it exists. You could also point out the typo in a comment. By answering, you make it harder to delete this question as it should be to avoid cluttering the site.

Comment: Good point @torazaburo, I wasn't aware that this "typo" close existed.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `;` from 3rd line. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the semicolon after the rule for the body.That causes the rest of the rules to be ignored.Remove it and your code will work.

```
body{
  background-color:gray;
 }

 h1 {
   text-align:center;
 }
```